# Docker - Simplest way to have centralized logging with multiple machines and log driver json-file?

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I have several servers where the docker deployment method is docker-compose.

All the containers simply log to stdout/stderr and the docker logging driver is the default `json-file` driver.

Is there a simple way to log all the containers in a centralized way?

Comment: You can use ELK (Elastic search, logstash, kibana) stack to simply setup centralized logging for your docker containers.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/monitoring-containerized-microservices-with-a-centralized-logging-architecture-ba6771c1971a ,  Have a look !

Comment: @SyedSaadAhmed could you please create an answer covering: the prerequisites (setting up elastic search/kibana server) with some resources and then going through step by step setting up logstash on a machine configured to use json-file driver? I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Telling you how to setup a complete infrastructure will be a bit difficult and lengthy.

These are some of the ways to maintain or get logs from the docker container. For elastic search, Kibana you can do some search you will easily get to know, how to setup.

Docker logs, are outputted to a JSON file. So, if you have a small Docker environment, you can use Filebeat to collect the logs. however you can also consider a different method. there are many others also

**Filebeat**

Filebeat belongs to the Beats family of log shippers by Elastic. Written in Go, Filebeat is a lightweight shipper that traces specific files, supports encryption, and can be configured to export to either your Logstash container or directly to Elasticsearch.

At the very least, your Filebeat configuration will need to specify the path to the JSON log file (located in /var/lib/docker/containers/…) and the details of the destination (usually the Logstash container).

An example configuration:

```
prospectors:     
 - paths:        
   - /var/log/containers/<xxx>          
   document_type: syslog     
output:
 logstash:  
  enabled: true  
  hosts:   
      - elk:5044
```

Some other ways are;

**Using a Logging Driver** or **Using Logspout** or **logzio**

Furthermore, Configure the filebeat configuration file to ship the logs to logstash. for that Edit /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml file

```
# — — — — — — — — — — Logstash output — — — — — — — — — —
output.logstash:
# The Logstash hosts
hosts: ["192.168.xx.xx:5044"]
```